# Open image in the browser instead of downloading it

Tags: reactjs, image, browser, window

I have a React component (avatar) that display image and I when I click the image it downloads it to my local machine. I don't want this behavior; I want that when the image clicked it opens in the browser.

I used `window.open` and `res.sendFile` in the back-end.

```
<MDAvatar
  src={`${imageConstLink}/imagePayed/${order.paymentCheckImage}`}
  name={order.paymentCheckImage}
  size="xl"
  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
  onClick={() =>
    window.open(`${imageConstLink}/imagePayed/${order.paymentCheckImage}`, "_blank")
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to do is wrap your `img` in a `a` tag, where the `src` of your component is the `href` in the link. Something like this:

```js
export const MDAvatar = ({ src, alt }) => {
  return (
    <a href={src} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
      <img src={src} alt={alt} />
    </a>
  );
};
```

Created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-morse-7x5qyp?file=/src/MDAvatar.js) so you can see it working.

Comment: it's not working for me it still downloads the image instead of displaying it and when I'm trying to display other images in my local folder it displays it but when I recieve the image from the backend it downloads it

Comment: @Bnw_Youcef can you console.log and show me the string `${imageConstLink}/imagePayed/${order.paymentCheckImage}` ?
There may be a hint on why it's downloading, instead of showing it

Comment: yes it's log: http://localhost:1811/order/image/1d5933dbe15d1977a0586f35a6652cce

Comment: Weird that doesn't have protocol (`http://`) and extension. Try to add those one, and see if that helps

Comment: Hi @Thremulant, I wanna contact you